# mySQL primary key oddity

Tags: php, mysql

I have a script which INSERT's data into a table and then later on when you INSERT new data it DELETE's the previous record/s and INSERT's the current data set.

The only issue is that the primary key gets wacked.

e.g. first four rows

```
1
2
3
4
```

then when i delete these and enter new data

```
5
3
4
6
```

note: the above numbers represent primary key id auto incrementations

Why does the incrementation become confused almost?

Comment: this should be impossible unless your delete also resets the auto_increment value?

Comment: Why not `truncate` instead?

Answer (score 2):

Auto-increment number do **not** get confused. They are unique over the table and that is the only purpose they have.

If you select the data then the DB will grab the records as fast as possible and if you do not specify a specific order then the records are returned in an unpredictable order.

That means if you specify

```
select * from your_table
order by id
```

Then the records have incrementing numbers. If you delete records then the gabs won't be filled.

Comment: his 3 and 4 are being 'recycled' which should not be possible

Comment: okay i understand that :) but mysql is synchronous right? so if you run a query to update a set of records then they execute one after another?

Comment: @Aiden: Yes, records are updated one after the other. But if you do not specify an order either then you can't say which one wil lbe updated first.

Comment: @Dagon: I doubt that happened. Probably just a misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to restart the numbers, use `truncate table` instead of `delete`.  This will reset the counter to 0:

```
truncate table <your table here>;
```